# Remove white background from b/w vector image for web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I have created schema in black and white vector image using Adobe Illustrator. Now I would like to make image for web. I choose GIF and save. Unfortunately I have A4 white background  where schema was created. I would like remove this background at all. How to achieve this?

UPD

It looks I did like described in answer below, but got picture wit huge backround anyway.
[image]
[image][image]

**UPD
OK I got it! "clip to artboard."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Three ways to do this...

**1) Remove the background**

If you have a white shape in your Illustrator as background, then delete it. I'm sure that's not your issue. By default, the background of Adobe Illustrator is transparent even though the artboard is white.

## or

**2) Check the box "transparency"**

When you do a "save for web", don't forget to check the box "transparency" when saving a gif or a png file.

[image: How to make transparent gif in Illustrator]

## or

**3) Remove the color with the color picker**

If you still have a background even if the box "transparency" is checked, then use the color picker tool on the top left of your "save for web" window, and click in the white background. Then, go on the right side where the color chart is, and click the first small icon; it will change the color you previously selected to transparent.

You can also do this by simply clicking on the white swatch on the right side color chart, and then clicking the small icon I mentioned above. You can do this for as many color as you want.

Note that this technique will remove ALL the white or the selected color on your gif!

[image: How to remove background color of a gif in save for web in Adobe Illustrator]

## Extra

If you don't want to see the A4 at all and only the graphics, you can uncheck the "clip to artboard."

[image: How to save for web gif or png without background or artboard]